# Mysql - Pesquisa usando like não retorna corretamente caracteres unicode

Tags: mysql, json

Tenho um editor de textos em minha aplicação que grava a formatação html em um campo longtext. Acontece que quando uso o like para retornar os dados ele não consegue encontrar por causa dos caracteres unicode gerados.

**Tenho esse valor no banco (Macarrão)**

```
<p>Macarr&atilde;o</p>
```

**Mysql**

```
select * from oficio where integra like '%Macarrão%' LIMIT 1
```

e ele não retorna registros. Como faço para que ele decode esse valor?

Comment: O melhor mesmo seria já guardar certo no banco. Normalmente você converteria para HTML na exibição apenas. Qualquer coisa que fizer em cima disso é sofrido, vai ter que ficar convertendo em toda operação (consulta, edição, etc). Não é porque seu editor devolve os dados assim que você vai gravar assim né. Vc pode converter as HTML Entities no encoding desejado e salvar no banco. Ao exibir na tela, gera as entities novamente, e o resto passa a funcionar. Basta converter as entities para o mesmo encoding nativo da sua tabela.

Comment: obrigado @Bacco, procurei na documentação do meu editor e resolvi o problema

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso estou usando o editor tinymce, acabei descobrindo que em sua configuração pode-se habilitar a opção para não gravar unicode

```
$scope.tinyMceOptions = {
      init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
        $scope.iframeElement = editor.iframeElement;
      },
      entity_encoding : "raw" //esta opção grava normalmente no banco
};
```

Comment: Só uma correção: unicode é uma coisa, entity é outra. O MySQL trabalha com unicode sem problemas, mas o seu exemplo da pergunta usa HTML entities (que foi o que você desligou com a configuração mencionada).